# python reload module for beginner. importlib.reload doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, module, python-import, reload

I have a file called skdb and class called skmysqldb.   I am trying to force reload.

I tried reloading "skdb", "skdb.skmysqldb" "skmysqldb" and none of them seem to work.

```
>>> from skdb import skmysqldb

>>> importlib.reload(skdb.skmysqldb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'skdb' is not defined

>>> importlib.reload(skmysqldb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 139, in reload
    raise TypeError("reload() argument must be a module")
TypeError: reload() argument must be a module

>>> importlib.reload(skdb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'skdb' is not defined
```

Comment: Hey @Nite could you add the code you are getting the error from.

Comment: what is the `skmysqldb`, is it a function? If so you can't reload it.

Answer (score 9):

When you import some object using the `from <module> import <obj>` syntax as in

```
from skdb import skmysqldb
```

the module itself is not added to the current namespace, hence why you get a `NameError` when you try to do `reload(skdb)`.

Instead try:

```
import skdb
importlib.reload(skdb)
```

Be cautious when using reload.  If the module your reload imports other modules, those modules are *not* reloaded recursively, so depending on the exact code you can wind up in a rather broken state where it's better to just restart the whole interpreter.

Comment: What if the module skmysqldb is a custom module and it's not in the same place as where you are importing it ? 
For example, 
`from server.settings import settings
importlib.reload(????)`

I can't make it work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported, but try doing `del sys.modules['mymodule']` for everything that vaguely matches. To find relevant ones, try something like `[x for x in sys.modules if 'mymodule' in x]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, `importlib.reload` is not working because there is a design defect in Python 3. The problem does not exist in Python 2.

As demonstrated below, if we install an earlier version of any pip package, import that package, then upgrade that package, then reload that package, you always get back to the same earlier version unless you quit and relaunch the interpreter.

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'yt-dlp==2023.3.3'])

import yt_dlp
print('before update:')
try:
        yt_dlp.main(['--version'])
except:
        pass

pip.main(['install', 'yt-dlp', '-U'])

import importlib
importlib.reload(yt_dlp)

print('after update:')
try:
        yt_dlp.main(['--version'])
except:
        pass
```

After running the above code, you get the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: yt-dlp==2023.3.3 in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2023.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.3) (1.45.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.3) (3.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.3) (10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.3) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp==2023.3.3) (1.0.9)
before update:
2023.03.03
Requirement already satisfied: yt-dlp in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2023.3.3)
Collecting yt-dlp
  Using cached yt_dlp-2023.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (1.45.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (3.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in /home/xuancong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (1.0.9)
Installing collected packages: yt-dlp
  Attempting uninstall: yt-dlp
    Found existing installation: yt-dlp 2023.3.3
    Uninstalling yt-dlp-2023.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled yt-dlp-2023.3.3
Successfully installed yt-dlp-2023.3.4
after update:
2023.03.03
```

As shown above, even when pip has successfully upgraded `yt-dlp` to version 2023.3.4, `yt_dlp` is still returning the old version number even after `importlib.reload` .